# how to include files with tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning, path

I am training Face-recognition model, So for **Triplet Loss**, I have to generate the batch such that it contains fixed amount of images from each label. For eg. I am saying that **take 8 images from 3 random labels** each time it generates batch for training, As suggested in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/omoindrot/tensorflow-triplet-loss/issues/7).

In my dataset folder **I have subfolder which is renamed as a label and contains the images of that folder.**

In the given issue, solution is presented,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

num_labels = len(path_list)
num_classes_per_batch = 3
num_images_per_class = 8

image_dirs = ["/content/drive/My Drive/smalld_processed/train/{:d}".format(i) for i in 
range(num_labels)]

## Create the list of datasets creating filenames

#datasets = [tf.data.Dataset.list_files(f"{image_dir}/*.jpg" for image_dir in image_dirs)]
datasets = [tf.data.Dataset.list_files(f"{image_dir}/*.jpg") for image_dir in image_dirs]
adk = ["{}/*.jpg".format(image_dir) for image_dir in image_dirs]
print(adk)

def generator():
    while True:
     # Sample the labels that will compose the batch
      labels = np.random.choice(range(num_labels),
                               num_classes_per_batch,
                               replace=False)
      for label in labels:
          for _ in range(num_images_per_class):
              yield label

choice_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, tf.int64)
dataset = tf.data.experimental.choose_from_datasets(datasets, choice_dataset)

## Now you read the image content
def load_image(filename):
    image = cv2.imread(filename,1)
    image = dataset.map(image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    image = image[...,::-1]
    label = int(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(filename))[1])
    image=dataset1.append()
    label=dataset2.append
    return image, label
   
dataset = dataset.map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
batch_size = num_classes_per_batch * num_images_per_class
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(None)
```

With this I am not able to load the images and it's showing me this error.

```
    SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Could you help me to **fix the error or any other suggestion on how to load images**.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case your `cv2.imread` is acting up. I would first build a simple program that does not do the reading "on the fly", but instead pre-loads images to train on a small dataset.

It also feels like you are misusing the dataset.map function. I would recommend this tutorial on the tf.data.Dataset function: http://tensorexamples.com/2020/07/27/Using-the-tf.data.Dataset.html, and maybe this one on augmentation so you can see how you should use the `map` function properly: http://tensorexamples.com/2020/07/28/Augmentation.html.

Good luck!